# Añadir sombras en cardview (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio, xml, android-layout, cardview

queria saber como añado sombras al cardview, he usado estos dos codigos pero se me añade por dentro y el gradient linear no es lo que busco, busco que las sombras salgan del cardview y sean negras como si estuviera elevado un poco del suelo y diera sombra no se si me explico bien

[image: img]

Este es el codigo del cardview en el fragmento, muestro solo la parte importante

```
<LinearLayout

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#3D3D3D"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/marco_cardview_videos"
            app:cardElevation="50dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/marco_cardview_videos">
```

En el 2 lineaLayout es donde tengo un drawable que tengo puesto el marco blanco del cardview

Este es el drawable que tengo para hacer el marco blanco que a la vez hace el intento de degradado

```
<shape xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
tools:ignore="ExtraText"
android:shape="rectangle">

<stroke
    android:width="3sp"
    android:color="@color/myWhite"/>



<padding
    android:bottom="8sp"
    android:left="8sp"
    android:right="8sp"
    android:top="8sp"/>

<corners android:radius="1dp"/>


<gradient
    android:type="linear"
    android:angle="45"
    android:startColor="#D3D3D3"
    android:endColor="#3D3D3D" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer los cardview de android studio tienen la clase ´cardElevation´ con la que puedes elevar mas la cardview o menos y se crean sombras automaticamente, el ejemplo que he usado.

```
app:cardElevation="150dp"
```